# Glossaries without {glossaries}

Tags: tables, glossaries

It appears to be somewhat tedious work to use the glossaries package and I prefer not having an explicit dependency on Perl scripts to process my LaTeX documents. So what I would ask is, how can one format a glossary nicely, without resorting to using the glossaries package?

I guess something between how a subparagraph looks but with tabular alignment.

LaTeX newbie here. :-)

Comment: This looks probably complicated if you're new to LaTeX but Nicola Talbot has written a nice article about [Creating a glossary without using an external indexing application](http://latex-community.org/component/content/article/55-latex-general/456-glossary-without-makeindex). I for my part find `glossaries` not too hard to use, actually...

Comment: Thanks - I'll read that! I just found out that my application Texpad, has an index typesetter. So it becomes simpler to use glossaries.

Comment: You can make the "explicit dependency" an "implicit one" with programs like `arara` or `latexmk` ;)